# Windows 10 adds English (United States) to the language preferences box (language bar)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, language, input-languages

Windows 10 adds English (United States) to the language preferences box
(language bar).

I found several answers, but the thing is they all make English (United States) as the default language, but I need only Russian and Japanese languages in the language bar (I have the English language included in the Japanese pack. I switch between them by pressing Caps Lock+Shift). So, the question is: what should I do in order to prevent English(United States) from adding on its own to the language bar?

This is what the language bar currently looks like:
[image: Language bar current look]

P.S. Maybe it's worth mentioning: I **don't have English (United States) in the Region and Language settings**, so that I need to add it and delete manually each time and it adds again shortly.

Comment: You've asked this question yesterday, didn't you? Next time please edit the old one instead of asking again, edits bump questions on the homepage and nominate closed questions for reopening. Btw, the question is very clear now, good job improving it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the rotation of switching layouts, then I can offer the KLA-8565 program
[Keyboard Layout Assistant 8565](http://kla-8565.mks.kyiv.ua)

It allows you to configure any language (up to four hotkeys, each with 1 of the main layouts). LShift / RShift / LCtrl / RCtrl

Note:
AltGr will then be intercepted (if you change the registry for the program).
If you leave it not intercepted, do not change the registry. The new version will have alternatives.

command (shortcut):

```
KLA_8565.exe /SNDmode=rel /SNDvol=20 /RShift=RU /LCtrl=JP /CapsLCtrl=off
```

file (KLA_8565.ini):

```
[DETECT_KEYBOARD_LAYOUT]
EN,0x4090409
RU,0x4190419
JP,0x4110411

[IGNORE_ALT_SPACE_CHANGER]
EN
```

[image]